# Google Script is passing the previous value of variable to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on Google Form. This form will collect data from user and then pass it into a Google Sheet to create a specific formatted report out of the data entered by the user in the form.

As the report has a specific format, so I must copy a template to avoid overwriting the original template.

I am facing issue as the data is entered to Google Sheet. Google Script is entering the previous value of variable "NewTempCopyName".

Below is the code:

```
 function onSubmit(e) {

      var NewTempCopyName = Utilities.formatDate( new Date(),"GMT+1","ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
      Logger.log(NewTempCopyName);

      var tmpsheet = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Form2 Template").next();
      tmpsheet.makeCopy(NewTempCopyName);
      var fid = tmpsheet.getId();
      var ss =SpreadsheetApp.openById(fid);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

      Logger.log(NewTempCopyName);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1").setValue(NewTempCopyName);
      Logger.log(NewTempCopyName);

    }
```

In the above code if the previous value of variable is 18092018114846 and the new value is 18092018115332 the script is passing 18092018114846 in B1.

The logger logs the correct value both before and after:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1").setValue(NewTempCopyName);
```

Comment: previous? when? Also, Your code suggests you're only modifying the template, not the copy.

Comment: James, Thanks for editing the question. Yes, you are correct, actually It was modifying the template, which I was not intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `NewTempCopyName` once, there would be no reason for it to change. Even though it is DateTime based, it doesn't update with time.

it is not clear which sheet you want to set the value of B1 within. If it is the copy you will need to make the following changes:

```
var newCopy = tmpsheet.makeCopy(NewTempCopyName);
var fid = newCopy.getId();
```

IF not, then would appear your code is functional as described; are you sure the Logger is listing different values between line 13 to line 15?

Comment: Jonathon, Thank you. It worked. It was a silly mistake. You are right actually it was modifying the template file.